# what are the benefit of using implicitly defined type for constants in swift programming language?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

In swift Programming language constants can expressed with let keyword like this

```
let MyConstant = 100
```

and implicitly defined with type name like below

```
let MyConstant: Int = 100
```

what are the benefit of using second method?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler infers the type to save you - the developer -  time. Why specify it when it's obvious from the value? Assuming it *is obvious*. I'll come to that shortly.

So if you can if you want to, what's the point? (*no pun intended*)

Perhaps for clarity; you wish to make it absolutely clear that the type of the variable is to be `Int`. The other purpose is that - in some cases, e.g. floating point types - the compiler's inferred default may not be what you desired. For example:

```
let MyConstant = 100.0
```

Double or Float? It assumes Double. If you want Float, you must be explicit:

```
let MyConstant: Float = 100.0
```

See [The Swift Programming Language: Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_988):

> In Swift, type information can also flow in the opposite
>   direction—from the root down to the leaves. In the following example,
>   for instance, the explicit type annotation (: Float) on the constant
>   eFloat causes the numeric literal 2.71828 to have type Float instead
>   of type Double.

```
    let e = 2.71828 // The type of e is inferred to be Double.
    let eFloat: Float = 2.71828 // The type of eFloat is Float.
```

> Type inference in Swift operates at the level of a single expression
>   or statement. This means that all of the information needed to infer
>   an omitted type or part of a type in an expression must be accessible
>   from type-checking the expression or one of its subexpressions.

Comment: Hi. Just reading over your answer here and wanted to ask: Would you happen to know how to break an expression into subexpressions?